# How can i get section of selected row from multiple section of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have multiple sections in my `UITableView` (about 12 sections) and each section has one or more rows. How can I get a section number in my `UITextField` Delegate method, when I select a row ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you added the textfield in the cell like

```
[cell.contentview addSubview:yourtextfield];
```

Then On the Textfield Delegate

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[textField superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

NSLog(@"your Indexpath %d",indexPath.section);
```

Comment: if u have added textfield in cell.contentview then [textfield superview] will return contentview of cell..

Answer (score 1):

When the user selects the row, your code needs to handle the call to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        ** your code here**
    }
```

the `indexPath` passed into this method contains both the section and the row. The best way to find out how to use it is to look at the documentation for NSIndexPath, but I believe that something like

```
indexPath.section
```

is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[textField superview];
    int section = [topicTable  indexPathForCell:clickedCell].section;
    NSLog(@"section %d", section);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it display tag value,text field value,try this code(use tag)

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

   NSLog(@"%d : %@", textField.tag,textField.text);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[textField superview]superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

NSLog(@"your Indexpath %d",indexPath.section);
```

however i suggest u in future create a customcell when performing tag operations with uitableviewcell

Comment: This was the correct answer before the accepted answered corrected his to this one.

Answer (score -1):

If you have manually created the table view in interface builder, i.e. with static cells then you could use tags in each UITextField and then check that in the delegate method.

For 12 sections you could number the tags as , e.g. 1203 is row 3 in section 12 or 600 is row 0 in section 6.

Comment: Terrible idea. Section 1 row 12 or section 11 row 2?

Comment: section as two digits e.g. ss, row as two digits e.g. rr so format is ssrr e.g. section 1 row 12 is 112 and section 11 row 2 is 1102

Comment: Missed that, but this is still a terrible idea when Apple provides a method already to do this. Doing it your way means parsing tags and knowing the upper bounds of your rows and sections before you start, and if you want to change those limits later in the apps lifecycle you have to redo the thing. Doesn't that smell hacky to you?

Comment: I agree. The superview answer is much better, especially for maintenance.